# Rails - Google Translate API : ArgumentError: unknown keyword: project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-translate

I have this code that was working on my rails app that is using google Translate API, but on my last commit to heroku I got the error

```rb
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: project
```

It seems that my google analytics is not working neither. Don't know what is causing the error. Maybe you have a hint ?

```rb
translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new project: "my_project"
description_translation = translate.translate params[:description], to: 'en'
update_attribute(:description, description_translation)
```

Comment: Are you using a gem for the api?  If so, which one?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes gem 'google-cloud' & gem 'google-cloud-translate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project` was an alias for `project_id`. It was [deprecated](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/commit/0f0990512533212cfeadea1e0d10b9e43217af09#diff-02d42d98f76560a0630fc17bc45da9c5L73) since version [`1.1.0`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-translate/CHANGELOG.md#110--2017-11-14) of the library.

Your code presumably stopped working because you updated the library to [version `2.0.0`](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-cloud-translate/versions/2.0.0) (or above) - since [here, in this PR](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/commit/0f0990512533212cfeadea1e0d10b9e43217af09#diff-02d42d98f76560a0630fc17bc45da9c5R174), support for the `project` parameter was fully dropped.

To fix this error, simply rename `project` to `project_id`.

Also take note of any other potentially-breaking changes [here, in the CHANGELOG](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-translate/CHANGELOG.md#200--2019-10-28). As shown in that link, you may wish to temporarily use `version: :v2` to help ease the migration if there are further complications.

Comment: I still have the same error ArgumentError: unknown keyword: project_id The google translate documentation is saying that it should be project not project_id. 
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

Comment: I don't see where that documentation says anything about `project` vs `project_id`? And regardless, that documentation appears to be for the `v2` API - which I have explained above how you can hopefully keep backwards-compatible support for, without downgrading the library. That website also shows how to keep using the `v2` API, exactly as I stated above: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/ruby

Comment: Digging a little deeper actually, I see the syntax for the `v3` API has changed significantly. You can see the usage [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/194aa0c6f8ebac5d36e7b96ec886daa719b5a45a/google-cloud-translate/OVERVIEW.md#translating-texts) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked with translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new version: :v2, project_id: "my_project"
I'll go through the documentation for V3! thanks a lot for your precious help !

Comment: ....OR, alternatively, if all else fails, you could just downgrade the library. You never actually stated (nor confirmed) that the error was caused by a library upgrade; this was my own assumption after taking the time to dig though documentation. But for future readers, this could be a vitally important piece of information to reveal.