# RuntimeError: Could not load the default credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-translate, google-cloud-translate

i've installed `google/cloud/translate` in my project, the version in the Gemfile.lock is:

```
google-cloud-translate (2.1.0)
```

With the below code:

```
require "google/cloud/translate"
project_id = "<Project ID>" # from my Google Cloud Platform
translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new version: :v2, project_id: project_id
```

That is what the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language?authuser=1) says and also what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58918041/6796652) related suggest (please note that i'm using v2 instead of v3)

```
RuntimeError: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information
```

This part returns true:

```
require "google/cloud/translate"
```

**Update**
I already followed all the steps in:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

Created a service account, a credential key and set the env variable (on Windows), then I tried testing the credential configuration with the `google/cloud/storage` example and it's worked fine, but when I tried with: `google/cloud/translate` gem with

`translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new version: :v2, project_id: project_id`

I still got the same error

What can be the error?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you not read https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials? It's telling you to go to that page to find out why it isn't working. And when you go to that page, it gives multiple examples of how to load your credentials into your app including `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. There are even Ruby code examples on that page to show how to do it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Hi for doing this you will need to have your .json file with all the keys of your google service account, once that you have that file in the same path of your project you could do something like the following code:

```
    module GoogleTranslator
        require "google/cloud/translate"
        ENV["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "yourfile.json"
        class Translate
            attr_reader :project_id, :location_id, :word, :target_language
            def initialize(project_id, location_id, word, target_language)
                @project_id         = project_id
                @location_id        = location_id
                @word               = word
                @target_language    = target_language
            end
    
            def translate
                client = Google::Cloud::Translate.translation_service
                parent = client.location_path project: project_id, location: location_id
                response = client.translate_text(parent: parent, contents: word.words.to_a, target_language_code: target_language)
                translate_content(response)
            end
    
            def translate_content(response)
                word.translation(response)
            end
        end
    end
    
    class Word
        attr_reader :words
        def initialize(words)
            @words = words
        end
    
        def translation(words)
            words.translations.each do |word|
                puts word.translated_text
            end
        end
    end
    
    module GoogleTranslatorWrapper
        def self.translate(project_id:, location_id:, word:, target_language:)
            GoogleTranslator::Translate.new(project_id, location_id, word, target_language)
        end
    end
    
    GoogleTranslatorWrapper.translate(project_id: "your_project_id_on_google", location_id: "us-central1", word: Word.new(["your example word"]), target_language: "es-mx").translate
```

Hope this can be clear :)...!

Comment: What's this location_id? Where does that come from?

Comment: when you create a new instance of translator you need to pass it, watch: ` def initialize(project_id, location_id, word, target_language)` this means that when you need to perform as follows,   `GoogleTranslatorWrapper.translate(project_id: "your_project_id_on_google", location_id: "us-central1", word: Word.new(["your example word"]), target_language: "es-mx").translate`the location_id is provided by google

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a service account:

   ```
   gcloud iam service-accounts create rubyruby --description "rubyruby" --display-name "rubyruby"
   ```
2. Get the service account name:

   ```
   gcloud iam service-accounts list
   ```
3. Create the credential key file for your service account:

   ```
   gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json --iam-account rubyruby@your-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
   ```
4. Set the env variable:

   ```
   export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json
   ```
5. Enable the translate API
6. Install the library:

   ```
   gem install google-cloud-translate
   ```
7. Edit the `ruby.rb` script

```
   # project_id = "Your Google Cloud project ID"
   # text       = "The text you would like to detect the language of"

   require "google/cloud/translate"
   text = 'I am home'

   translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new version: :v2, project_id: project_id
   detection = translate.detect text

   puts "'#{text}' detected as language: #{detection.language}"  
   puts "Confidence: #{detection.confidence}"
```

8. Run the script:

   ```
   ruby ruby.rb
   ```
9. Output:

   ```
   'I am home' detected as language: en
   Confidence: 1
   ```

Comment: I already followed all the steps from https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production, created a service account, a credential key and set the env variable (on Windows), then I tried testing the credential configuration with the "google/cloud/storage" example and it's worked fine, but when I tried with "google/cloud/translate" gem with ```translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new version: :v2, project_id: project_id```, I still got the same error

Comment: @ManuelCarrero Go back to the page and read the whole thing. There is a dead simple example of using `keyfile` during your `.new` call to tell it to load a specific keyfile. All the answers to your question are on that page.